# Calling product model overriding default product on Product Detail page

Tags: magento

I'm stuck here. The client wanted to have a random product display on the product detail page (in the product upsell section). I chose to not use the built in upsell feature for multiple reasons, but there is not need to discuss that.

I'm currently displaying a random product like so:

```
<?php

    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(9);
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->load();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $result[$product->getId()] = $product;
    }

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(array_rand($result, 1));

?>

<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>">

    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(190); ?>" />

    <?php echo $_product->getName(); ?><br />
    <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()); ?>

</a>
```

The issue is that by calling Mage::getModel('catalog/product'), I believe that the current product is being overwritten. For example, when I click on the 'add to cart' button, my custom featured upsell product is being added to the cart rather than the actual product in the product detail page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you're overriding the `$_product` variable that the default template uses. Use your own variable name and you'll be fine

```
$_myProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(array_rand($result, 1));
```